# ActiveSync - MAPI bridge

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, activesync

Is anybody aware of a piece of software bridging MAPI and ActiveSync ? Preferably open source. Or alternatively, a MAPI <-> IMAP solution could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but it looks like [Z-Push](http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/) fits your needs. It's open source and bridges ActiveSync to IMAP.